# Creating a variable to fit all class type

Tags: c#, class

Is it possible to create a variable that represent many class object and call a function that exist in all that class?
I want to create something like this..

```
class A{
    void DoSomething(){
        //some code
    }
}

class B{
    void DoSomething(){
        //some code
    }
}

class Controller{
    public ClassType theObject;
    public void DoSomething(){
        theObject.DoSomething();
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(){
        A objectA = new A();
        B objectB = new B();
        Controller objectC = new Controller();

        objectC.theObject = objectA;
        objectC.DoSomething();

        objectC.theObject = objectB;
        objectC.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Is anyone know how to do this (what keyword to change the `ClassType` in class `Controller`) or what keyword I need to use to search something like this?

Comment: Are you looking for interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an [**Interface**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms173156) and let both classes A and B implement it.

```
interface ICanDoSomething {
    void DoSomething();
}

class A : ICanDoSomething {
    void DoSomething(){
        //some code
    }
}

class B : ICanDoSomething{
    void DoSomething(){
        //some code
    }
}

class Controller {
    public ICanDoSomething theObject;
    public void DoSomething(){
        theObject.DoSomething();
    }
}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to keep the answer as similar to your code as possible. What you are looking are called interfaces. As a very basic explanation, classes that implement interfaces are required to provide code for each method that is defined in the interface. Hence by polymorphism, you are able to assign an instance of a concrete class such as `A` and `B` to a `ClassType`, which is your interface. You can then call any method that is defined in the interface on the object that is currently assigned.

```
interface ClassType
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class A : ClassType
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        //some code
    }
}

class B : ClassType
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        //some code
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main()
    {
        A objectA = new A();
        B objectB = new B();
        ClassType objectC;

        objectC = objectA;
        objectC.DoSomething();

        objectC = objectB;
        objectC.DoSomething();
    }
}
```